# Remove heading tags on line break

Tags: functions, tinymce, html, editor, visual-editor

I have to add line breaks in a h1 paragraph using the visual editor. On every line break Wordpress automatically adds h1 tags to every new line.

Example:

```
<h1>Watsup</h1>
<h1>World</h1>
```

How can I prevent the code on top and instead get:

```
<h1>Watsup<br />
World</h1>
```

Note: I can't use the text editor. It has to work with visual editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use Shift + Enter.

[Soft and Hard Returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Soft_and_hard_returns).

Comment: Thanks I tried. It doesn't create new lines when viewing the HTML.

Comment: disable plugins, switch to a default theme and test.